# method does not override or implement a method from a supertype: How can make override work?

Tags: java, annotations, overriding, implements

I really searched a lot to find the answer to this error message but somehow nothing I have found so far answered my question.

```
public interface TileGenerator {

int NUMBER_OF_MOVABLE_TILES = 34;
int NUMBER_OF_LAST_MAGIC_ITEM = 25;
int NUMBER_OF_CONTIGUOUS_MAGIC_ITEMS = 20; 
ArrayList<Tile> createTiles();

ArrayList<MagicItem> createMagicItems();

}
```

and my subclass:

```
public class RandomTileGenerator implements TileGenerator {

private static final int FIVE = 5;

private static final int THIRTEEN = 13;

private static final int SIXTEEN = 16;

private static final int TWENTYONE = 21;

private static final int TWENTYFIVE = 25;

private static final int TWENTY = 20;

private ArrayList<Tile> list2 = new ArrayList<Tile>(NUMBER_OF_MOVABLE_TILES);

@Override
public ArrayList<Tile> createTiles() {

    for (int x = 0; x < FIVE; x++) {
        list2.add(new Tri());
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < THIRTEEN; x++) {
        list2.add(new Straight());
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < SIXTEEN; x++) {
        list2.add(new Nook());
    }

    Collections.shuffle(list2);
    return list2;
}

@Override
public ArrayList<MagicItem> createMagicItems() {
    int i = 1;
    ArrayList<MagicItem> magicItemFound = new ArrayList<MagicItem>();
    for (int x = 0; x < TWENTYONE; x++) {

        magicItemFound.add(new MagicItem(i));
        i++;

    }

    magicItemFound.set(TWENTY, new MagicItem(TWENTYFIVE));

    Collections.shuffle(magicItemFound);

    return magicItemFound;

}

}
```

But I always get the error message:

```
Labyrinth3Test.java:477: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
            @Override
```

I have no clue how to override it the right way, as it seems that my Override annotation is completely useless.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: `Error Message: Labyrinth3Test.java:477` => The problem is on line 477 of `Labyrinth3Test.java`, which you have not shown in your question...

Comment: Because i don't have this test... we (student) are uploading code and then there are tests running And we don't have these tests :(

Comment: My guess is that your teacher expects you to use a different signature for the methods... Did he/she give you the code of the interface? If not did you get guidelines?

Comment: No Code but guidelines yes but theyr only saying that we should "hide" the process of creating tiles behind an Interface called TileGenerator and the implementations Fixed and Random Tile Generator (i only uploaded one of them because the error messages are the same :/)

Comment: found the mistake thank you anyway :)